# Sip file syntax error

Tags: python, qt4, pyqt4, python-sip

I am creating a SIP file to control the building of multiple .sip files for a project I've been working on. I used one of the files the comes with PyQt as an example on how to build one file that will import other .sip files and build them in one call to 'sip'. When I run my configure.py script I get the ouput:

```
sip: syntax error
```

My main .sip file that I am trying to run with sip is as follows:

```
%Module(name=MyModule, keyword_arguments="All")

%Import QtGui/QtGuimod.sip

%ModuleHeaderCode
#include <MyModule_global.h>
%end

%Include mymodule.sip
%Include node.sip
```

I can't seem to find any obvious syntax errors. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

After %ModuleHeaderCode
Try: %End instead of %end